# How Java and NodeJS communicate in backend?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I have already done a project using jsp as backend, while the business logic in backend is implemented by java. Now I want to rewrite this project.I hope the part of backend communicating with browser is implemented with nodejs and the business logic in backend still use java to implement.Now I met with a problem about how to communicate between nodejs and java in backend. Is there any feasible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is a standalone runtime environment (based on V8, which is implemented in C++).  Since it is not based on Java technology it has no "simple" way to communicate with Java code running in a JVM.

Integrating unrelated technologies, such as these two, is typically done by using some sort of [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), for example, TCP sockets or a message queue with bindings native to each platform (e.g. [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/)).  Creating a [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) interface is another possible option.

[Searching the web for keywords such as "node.js java bridge"](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+java+bridge) yields a number of interesting results.

Comment: Thank for your reply.It's really helpful to me.I will try these methods.I also find a related topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200869/java-nodejs-communicating-via-socket-bad-idea).There are also some ideas I hope will be of value to you.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think u can check this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/java

Using this you can call method of java from node.js