# Multiplayer client/server game using Javascript/JSP/Java

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to implement a small multiplayer client/server game. It's my concurrent program project. I wrote the application's basic logic in Java and it's working. I want to make it web based. I am not sure how to do it. Here is a small part that I want to implement:

```
<%@page import="javacode.Client"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    Client client = new Client();
        boolean b = client.connect();
%>
<%= b%>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendToServer(){
        var line = document.getElementById("input").value;
        //send line to server using client.send()
        client.send(line);
        //get response from server to client using client.get()
        line = client.get();
        document.getElementById("input").value=line;
    }
</script>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="input" id="input"/>
        <input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendToServer()"/>
        <input type="text" name="output" id="output" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I am starting a chat echo server then opening this JSP page. It's connecting to the server by creating a client object. But I want to use the same client object for further communication with the server. Whenever I click the send button it has to get an input field's value and send it to the server, then get the response from the server with the `client.get()` method and set the value to output field. As a Java program `Client.java` is working fine, but I am not sure how to do it web based.

PS: I don't want to use an applet.

Comment: Check out nodejs and socket.io

Comment: all those will be new to me. can't we do it using jquery/javascript and jsp?

Comment: Those have a fairly short time of learning curve, you are familiar with jquery and javascript which is an advantage for you. It is your decision, of course it can be made. Have a read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200869/java-nodejs-communicating-via-socket-bad-idea

Comment: my project deadline is even shorter :( i have only 2 weeks of time. any suggestions how to do it? I have tried with jquery but everytime i send request to jsp page, it creating new object.

Comment: i have solved it by storing client object in session variables